# how to know what type of project in visual studio

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to reverse engineer a windows source code.

there is a solution which contains different projects...
How do I know exactly if a project is of type win32 Project or of type win32 console application? placing the project.vcxproj file in notepad I only notice win32<\platform>, which infact doesn't differentiate from win32 console application or win32 project

Comment: What type of program are these projects?

Comment: Do you not have access to an executable copy of the program? Ie, PEiD "Portable Executable ID" will tell you in a heartbeat (as would running it)

Comment: What do you have? And how would you reverse engineer from source? That's forward engineering. Reverse engineering is when you start with finished product and generate source.

Comment: @David Heffernan please what do you mean by what do I have? I had source code and executables but now only  the source codes

Comment: Compile the source and hey presto, executables

Comment: What helpful information do you hope to deduce from figuring out, what type a project is (or was), that will help you 'reverse' engineering the source code? How would you interpret a function called `foo` differently, if it were in a DLL vs. a GUI application?

Comment: if you have the source code you can search for `main` or `WinMain`, console programs implement `main`, GUI programs implement `WinMain`.

Comment: @nate ,that was an important input, the thing is that there is a project called "comune" in the solution which has soo many .cpp files, like 25 of them, these .cpp files are namespaces which are called in other gui projects all residing in the same solution, I'm yet to find a winMain or main entry point in one of the .cpp files in project comune... 
so it looks like project comune has .cpp files which contains codes needed in the other projects in the solution. I hope this makes things clearer

Comment: so after finding no entrypoint of type main or WinMain in project comune, I conclude that is it an empty project which contains code of namespaces and other support codes for the other projects, because so far thats only whats is doing.

Comment: If it doesn't have `main` or `WinMain`, it must be a library. If it is a dynamic link library, there should be an entry point named `DllMain` otherwise it sounds like a static link library.

Comment: @nate, great input again, you've solved all my problems, I can't give thanks because stackoverflow police force will be in telling me this place is not for socialization, is it a static link library!

Answer (score 2):

By default a GUI subsystem project has linker option `/subsystem:windows`. A console project does not. But this can be changed later at will, so you can't *know* exactly what the original project type was.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get to these linker options? I just went into project properties, linker...but I can't find nothing like /subsystem:windows, pls remember I'm using visual studio 2015

Comment: @IngMike: *"remember I'm using visual studio 2015"* - Well, apparently you aren't. Simply open the linker settings tab of the project settings in Visual Studio, and read the value of the `/SUBSYSTEM` setting. It cannot possibly get any easier than that...

Comment: @IInspectable I found but not as simply as you stated it, if things are said more clearly and specifically, it will help a lot...project tab, then common properties, Linker, then System, then one has subsystem, is not like is the same thing as you said... :/

Comment: @IngMike: There is only one `/SUBSYSTEM` setting per project. I didn't assume you were **this** lost. It's not very common to hold users' hands through their first baby steps using an IDE at stackoverflow. Q&A's assume a basic level of understanding.

Comment: @IInspectable, so what about if I've been using codeblocks ide forever and I just migrated to visual studio, I believe a good programmer should never assume, just like the code we write never assume parameters or conditions till we clearly specify them, and please I believe stackoverflow is for people who are "this" lost, or else may be one can be made to fill a form to check if one is at the level of a researcher before one is made to register, that said if you can help just help or maybe just ignore?

Answer (score 1):

In our .vcxproj files for console applications, I noticed that
`_CONSOLE` appears as one of the items in the cdata of the `PreprocessorDefinitions` element. There maybe other cues for console applications.

Answer (score 1):

In my version of VS (Community 2015), when I create a new Win32 Project, it contains non-console-app files such as `Resource Files/*.ico`. If the `ReadMe.txt` is still there, that may also have clues.

If you want to recreate a project, I'd say just make an educated guess about which it is (based on what type of program it is) and try pasting the code into a new project of that type. If there are errors, either you chose the wrong one or the project has other settings that the author set.

Judging from the variety of answers here, I'd say that your best bet is to do some snooping in the settings, look for clues, use your judgement, and then just try it out.